# Python main error

Tags: python

```
import sys

def Cat(filename):

    f = open(filename,'rU')
    text = f.read()
    print ("text")
    f.close()

    def main():
        Cat(sys.argv[1])  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I keep getting the following error shown below:

```
NameError: name 'main' is not defined.
```

Comment: Is that indentation correct? Why is `main` nested within the `Cat` function?

Comment: Well, name `main()` IS NOT defined. `Cat().main()` is defined. But `main()` is not.

Comment: Why have a main function at all if it's only one line? Why not do `if __name__ == '__main__': Cat(sys.argv[1])`?

Comment: @Kevin: In this case it's the same. In more complex examples you're cluttering the namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

main is not indented properly. It should have no indentation.
Now it is only accessible from Cat.

```
import sys

def Cat(filename):

    f = open(filename,'rU')
    text = f.read()
    print ("text")
    f.close()

def main():
    Cat(sys.argv[1])  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I removed the indentation and is still getting the same error.

Comment: I copied and pasted my example into a python file. Saved and ran it without error.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'm going to copy and paste on a new file. I really appreciate the follow up.